# Read the Docs autodoc seems to fail on Python 3.6 formatted string

Tags: python, python-3.x, documentation, read-the-docs

I'm using the Sphinx autodoc feature in making documentation for my Python project. Building the HTML locally works fine, but it seems to fail on [Read The Docs](https://readthedocs.org/). I have RTD connected to my Github account, with a hook on commit. It seems to be reading my code and importing the package just fine.

The error I see seems to indicate that it's failing because of the formatted strings in my Python code:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'letterboxd.api'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/letterboxd/envs/latest/lib/python3.5/site-packages/letterboxd-0.1.0a5-py3.5.egg/letterboxd/api.py", line 77
    headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {self.user.token}"
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am running Python 3.6 locally, so my *guess* is that the issue may be that Read the Docs doesn't support 3.6 yet. I do have the RTD Admin > Advanced Settings > Python interpreter set to CPython 3.x, and have also checked the box for “Install your project inside a virtualenv using `setup.py install`”

Is this currently a known issue with RTD, or is there some setting I can tweak to correct this?

Comment: Looks like it was fixed in 2017: https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2581 Do you have an old read the docs build?

Comment: @sehafoc I'm uploading to the public RTD site, so I would assume it's the latest. But maybe this YAML configuration file mentioned is the key. Will investigate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [bug link](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2581) that @sehafoc provided in a comment above (thanks!), I read and clicked through to find [this doc page](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yaml-config.html#build-image) about building a YAML config file for RTD.

Adding this config file resolved this issue, where `build:image:` and `python:version:` are the relevant bits:

```
# .readthedocs.yml

build:
  image: latest

python:
  version: 3.6
  setup_py_install: true

requirements_file: requirements.txt
```